# How to get the cell position/row of a search result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to compare a cell containing a long string (A1) with a list of keywords (C:C). I want to get the first matching cell position in order to reference the value in the corresponding array (D:D).

I've tried this: 
=INDEX(D:D;SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C:C;A1))*ROW(1:1)))

but this seems wrong: the number returned from the SEARCH function is NOT a row number but the number of characters in common between the find_text and within_text values.

e.g.:

A1 contains "Hello World"

C1 "Random"
C2 "Keyword"
C3 "World"

D1 "fail"
D2 "fail"
D3 "success"

I want to have in B1 a formula that takes A1, look if it contains one of the values in C:C and if yes, reference the corresponding value from D:D.

This means here I would get "success" in B1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE to return the row number to the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C$1:$C$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$C$1:$C$3&" "," "&A1&" "))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I normally uses wildcard. This should work too.

=INDEX(D1:D3,MATCH("*World*",C1:C3,0))